# ClearInterval() and SetInterval()

Tags: javascript

So in my javascript code, there is a part where if the user clicks on the checkbox I need to change the time delay used by `setInterval()`. At the moment, I used the `onchange` handler on the checkbox. Whenever the checkbox is changed, I call `clearInterval()` and `setInterval()`. I have the interval id as a global variable. Now if the user changes the checkbox before i have made my call to `clearInterval()` I expected there to be some issues, but nothing happened. Is there a better way to do this or is this way considered standard? Is there a way to check if there is an `interval` in existence?

PS.
I'm very new to Javascript, started it about 5 hours ago.

Comment: You might take a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval) so that you are quite clear of the available options

Comment: Why don't you post some code (you can edit your post).  jsFiddle is a good place to put sample Javascript code.

Comment: Show us your code and we can give you more specific advice.  Javascript is single threaded so timers will NOT ever be executed while your javascript event handler is running so you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 var myInterval = setInterval(...);

 document.getElementById('myCheckbox').onchange = function()
 {
   var func = arguments.callee;
   if (func.busy) return;
   func.busy = true;
   clearInterval(myInterval);
   myInterval = setInterval(...);
   func.busy = false;
 }
```

Comment: Javascript is single threaded so a timer interval will NEVER interrupt the currently executing javascript.  Thus, you do NOT need to protect your code with busy flags like you're doing.  I don't see how this solves anything.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks for your feedback. I am aware of this, but I got the impression that ZachSchnider was getting some weird behavior and this does answer his question, as he described it.

Comment: @LiorCohen Thanks for your response. I was not getting an error, your answer did clear a lot of things.